# finding the type of a function

Tags: integration, functions

$f$ is a productive function. $f: (0,+ \infty) \to \mathbb R$ for which it applies $f(1)=2$ and $$x^2 f'(x) + x f(x)=1 \, \forall  x>0.$$
Find the type of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hint***

$$x^2 f'(x) + x f(x)=1$$
$$x f'(x) + f(x)=\frac 1 x$$
$$(xf(x))'=\frac 1 x$$

$$xf(x)=\ln(x)+K$$
$$f(1)=2 \implies K=2$$
$$\boxed{f(x)=\frac {\ln(x)+2}x}$$